# Joint pdf and definition of conditional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

If I have a joint pdf of the following form
$$
f(X \leq x, Y = y)
$$
where $X$ and $Y$ are continuous random variables. Can the definition of conditional probability be applied such that
$$
f(X \leq x, Y = y) = P(X \leq x|Y=y)f(Y=y)
$$
?

This seems valid to me, but is $P(X \leq x|Y=y)$ a probability or a pdf in itself?

Answer (score 1):

It is a conditional cumulative distribution function; so measures a probability mass.

Comment: Whether we condition on a discrete or continuous variable doesn't change that right?